# What's the `tek` namespace often used in XLIFF files?

Tags: xliff

I'm investigating about XLIFF, and for a start, wanted to have some tests with HTML files. I found an XSL Transformation at OASIS, which produces XLIFF files from HTML files. But the resulting XLIFF files contains elements and attributes belonging to a `tek` name‑space, which OpenLanguageTools XLIFF Editor seems to not enjoy. I, myself, have issue trying to validate it against the `xliff-core-1.2-strict.xsd` schema.

I wonder what's that `tek` name‑space, whose identifier is `http://www.tektronix.com/TC` . I searched the web, but could found nothing relevant.

Is this a standard extension to XLIFF? Is this legacy or actual?

**Update #1**: What troubles me a lot, is that the URL seems not valid any‑more, and redirects to www.tek.com now, while there seems to be still many sample XLIFF documents holding elements from to that name‑space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tek` stands for [Tektronix](http://www.w3.org/International/multilingualweb/dublin/slides/23-schnabel.pdf) indeed. Although you didn't provide the resulting Xliff, but I guess the reason that you're not able to validate it against the Xliff core schema is that your document has two namespaces; the original Xliff namespace and a custom namespace called `tek` which is used to add customized vocabulary to the file.

Here is a `foo` example:

```
<xliff xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2" 
       xmlns:foo="http://www.foobar.com"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2         
       xliff-core-1.2-strict.xsd http://www.foobar.com foo.xsd" 
       version="1.2">
```

Then you can have:

```
   <trans-unit id="0" restype="button" resname="big_red_button">
       <foo:serious-note>Srsly!</foo:serious-note>
       <source xml:lang="en-US">Don't push here!</source>
       <target state="needs-translation></target>
   </trans-unit>
```

And as long as you add this customized tag to your schema, you can validate the file using *both* Xliff schema and your customized schema:

```
<xsd:element name="serious-note">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:simpleContent>
            <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:attribute ref="xml:lang" use="optional"/>
                <xsd:attribute name="foobar" type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Comment: Do you know why I've seen this particular extension name‑space so much often? Was a kind of de‑facto standard? What's its current status? Should I care or should I study XLIFF without taking care of this foreign extension?

Comment: I guess folks at Tektronix had a big role in OASIS so lots of examples probably came from them and therefore use that namespace. Actually as shown above, it's just a customization. I've seen other companies do the same to add their own customized tags to Xliff and prevent mixing of customized vocabulary with standard Xliff vocabulary.

Comment: “I guess folks at Tektronix had a big role in OASIS”; OK, now I understand.